# WebdriverJS dump to terminal?

Tags: javascript, webdriver

I am finding it very difficult to debug a test using WebDriverJs because I don't know how to see the value of a variable.  For example, I am trying to access the window handle of a pop-up.  I can test .toNotBe(null), but I would like to know the actual value.  Every time I want to use it in the next logical step of driver.switchTo().window(handle) I get the error that NameOrHandle is not defined.  That is probably the next question on SO; but for now I just want to know what node thinks "handle" is if not null but still not defined.

Is there a dump() command, or a helper library I can load into my spec with require that will allow me to dump an object's value to the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to console.log() to dump your output to the terminal. For example:

```
driver.getAllWindowHandles().then(function(windows){
    var originalWindow = windows[0];
    var popupWindow = windows[1];

    if (popupWindow) {
        driver.switchTo().window(popupWindow);
        driver.getTitle().then(function(popupTitle){
            console.log("popupTitle is set to: ", popupTitle);
            next();
        });
    }
});
```